# Impose relation between partial derivatives of functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, symbolic

I have very long expressions with functions `f[x,y]` and `g[x,y]` which satisfy

```
Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] == - Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]
```

I want to simplify expressions such as

```
Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] - Derivative[1, 1][g][x, y]
```

which should evaluate to zero.

Ideally, the relation between the functions would only be imposed locally (comparable to the local definitions of variables inside a `Block` or similar).

### What I have tried so far

I have found a solution which is non-local and also works only in the simplest cases. Using the function `SetDelayed`

```
Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] := Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]
```

correctly evaluates expressions like

```
Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] - Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]
```

to zero, but not

```
Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] - Derivative[1, 1][g][x, y]
```

Interestingly, with the above `SetDelayed` the following evaluates to zero:

```
D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] - D[g[x, y], x, y]
```

Comment: So why not add `Derivative[k_Integer?Positive, 0][f][x_, y_] := Derivative[k - 1, 1][g][x, y]` as a definition?

Comment: @J.M. This does indeed work for the examples I have provided but misses, for example, `Derivative[1, 1][f][x, y] - Derivative[0, 2][g][x, y]`.

Comment: Yes, because the previous definition fixed the order of the partial with respect to the second variable. I was nudging you to think carefully about the general rule for implementing `Derivative[j, k][f][x, y]`.

Comment: I see. `Derivative[j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive][f][x_, y_] := 
 Derivative[j - 1, k + 1][g][x, y]`. Thanks a lot. Do you think it is ok to put `ImposeRelation[expr_] := Block[{}, Derivative[j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive][f][x_, y_] := 
 Derivative[j - 1, k + 1][g][x, y]; expr]`?

Comment: If you want to account for `0`, use `NonNegative` instead as the condition. I don't know about OK; why not just try it out? You can always start in a fresh kernel if things go south for some reason.

Comment: OK, good point. Thanks again.

Comment: Since you figured it out, you could write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments by [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) the definition using `SetDelayed` can be extended to an arbitrary number of partial derivatives:

```
Derivative[j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?NonNegative][f][x_, y_] :=
  Derivative[j - 1, k + 1][g][x, y]
```

To satisfy the requirement of locality the following may be used:

```
ImposeRelation[expr_] := 
  Block[{fL, gL}, 
    Derivative[j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?NonNegative][fL][x_, y_] :=
      Derivative[j - 1, k + 1][gL][x, y]; 
    expr /. {f -> fL, g -> gL} /. {fL -> f, gL -> g}]
```